# EF 4.1 Eager loading first 5 child records is it possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, eager-loading

Using EF 4.1 I have a model (customer with associated purchases) and I want to create a brief overview page showing customers and their last 5 purchases.   Is there a way to create a search using EF 4.1 where I get say all customers with a name of 'bret and use eager loading to only load their last 5 purchases?  I understand ef 4.1 supports eager loading using include but can you specify a limit with an order by?

Comment: I don't think its possible. it will have to create complex queries by partitioning sub queries.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't specify limit for eager loadig. You can do it only in explicit loading for single customer:

```
var customer = context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId);
context.Entry(customer)
       .Collection(c => c.Purchases)
       .Query()
       .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
       .Take(5)
       .Load();
```

If you want to do it for multiple customers in single query you must use projection:

```
var query = context.Customers
                   .Select(c => new {
                        Customer = c,
                        Purchases = c.Purchases.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).Take(5)
                    });
```

Be aware that you must project to custom or anonymous type. You cannot project back to `Customer` class.

Comment: Using ef 4.1 I tried to query using projection and an anonymous type but I get the following error. "Specified method is not supported."